# d3.rollup returns blank object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Below is the sample JSON trying to pass it to d3.rollup

`const data = [ { "date": "2000-01-01", "name": "Coca-Cola", "category": "Beverages", "value": 72537 }, { "date": "2000-01-01", "name": "Microsoft", "category": "Technology", "value": 70196 }, { "date": "2000-01-01", "name": "IBM", "category": "Business Services", "value": 53183 } ]`

below is my func :

`populateDateValues() { datevalues = Array.from(d3.rollup(data, ([d]) => d.value, d => +d.date, d => d.name)) .map(([date, data]) => [new Date(date), data]) .sort(([a], [b]) => d3.ascending(a, b)) }`

it is returning :

`[[null,{}]]`

trying to pass value into d3.rollup() and not receiving the expected value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Made some adjustments and getting the output some minor syntactical errors were there like function was not defined and dateValue datatype was also not defined
here is the fix hope it works  :

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const data = [
    // ... (your data objects)
  {
    "date": "2000-01-01",
    "name": "Coca-Cola",
    "category": "Beverages",
    "value": 72537
}, {
    "date": "2000-01-01",
    "name": "Microsoft",
    "category": "Technology",
    "value": 70196
}, {
    "date": "2000-01-01",
    "name": "IBM",
    "category": "Business Services",
    "value": 53183
}
];

function populateDateValues() {
    const dateValues = Array.from(
        d3.rollup(
            data,
            group => d3.sum(group, d => d.value),
            d => d.date,
            d => d.name
        )
    ).map(([date, value]) => [new Date(date), value])
    .sort(([a], [b]) => d3.ascending(a, b));

    return dateValues;
}


// Call the function and store the result
const result = populateDateValues();
console.log(result);
```

This is the output which you will get :

```
[
  [
    2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    InternMap(3) [Map] {
      'Coca-Cola' => 72537,
      'Microsoft' => 70196,
      'IBM' => 53183
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: HI ,

tried your code , it is returning me undefined

Comment: I did run on it my machine it gives the exact output which I've  put on the post !

Comment: Here I am attaching a screenshot of the output to the code and the code running on vscode ! hope it helps ! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bqFf7KfgOBPgaggU6fmqI2Eq62JcKkbe/view?usp=sharing